# Android Notifications won't show up

Tags: android

I've implemented following method for showing some notifications in android. The method is very similar to the developer.android.com tutorial, but my notifications won't show up, neither on 4.1 nor on 4.0 or 2.3.

```
public void showNotification() {
    String appname = "App Name";
    String title = "Notification Title";
    String text = "This is the notification text";
    String iconUrl = "http://url.to.image.com/image.png";
    Bitmap largeIcon = imageCache.getBitmap(iconUrl);
    NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.from(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NewsActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(context, NewsActivity.class));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(title).setContentInfo(appname).setLargeIcon(largeIcon).setContentText(text).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notifyManager.notify("textid", 123, builder.getNotification());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [small icon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)) is a required element of the notification.

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
```

This is the icon that shows up in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
notifyManager.notify("textid", 123, builder.build());
```